# Unable to inject $http into a factory

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to inject `$http` into a `factory` but i'm getting this error:

`Error: Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http <- utilService`

Here is my `factory` code:

```
var util = angular.module('util', [])
.factory('utilService', ['$http', function($http) {             
    return {
        translate: function(objects, prop) {
            var keys = objects.map(function(o) {return o[prop];});      
            $http({method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/messages', data: keys}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                return objects.map(function(o, rank) {return {'value': data[rank], 'object': o}});
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The code of the controller where i use the service:

```
var app = angular.module('recordController', ['ui.bootstrap','dialogs', 'util']);

function records($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout, $dialogs) {

  var utilService = angular.injector(['util']).get('utilService');

  $scope.showForm = false;
  $scope.states= [];

  $scope.toggleForm = function() {
    $scope.showForm = !$scope.showForm;

    if($scope.showForm) {
        if(!$scope.states.length) {
            $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest/records/state'}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.states = utilService.translate(data, 'state');   
            });
        }
    }
  };

  ...
};
```

And the `HTML`:

```
    <div ng-app='recordController'>
      <div ng-controller='records' >    
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Is something wrong with it? I have been searching for some insight in StackOverflow and Google but couldn't find any hint about what's wrong.

Comment: Can you also paste the code where you are using utilService?

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: I edited the question with some context.

Comment: Where is the function "records" defined? In window or encapsulated scope (function(){... function records .... })(); ?

Comment: Why are you using `angular.injector` to get `utilService`? Just use Angular's DI to get it. But, if you want to keep it that way, I believe that if you inject `ng` like so `angular.module('util', ['ng'])` it will fix your problem.

Comment: the factory should take two arguments name and a function. But you are sending a list as second argument why is that. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#factory

Comment: @AnsumanBebarta He's doing it the right way: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: @ricardo-amaral i'm new to angular and still don't know well how it works. Well, i injected ng and i'm not getting the error, but the POST request is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really tested any of this but I believe your problem can be fixed in multiple ways:

### 1

Use `angular.module('util', ['ng'])` instead of `angular.module('util', [])`.

### 2

Use `app.get('utilService')` instead of `angular.injector(['util']).get('utilService')`.

### 3

Get rid of `var utilService = angular.injector(['util']).get('utilService');` and add `utilService` as the last parameter of the `records` function. I'm not really sure this works as I normally don't use this form of declaration.

If #3 works, use that, if not use #2. Use #1 only if you have to.

Also, you did not post the part of the code where `records` is used, but make sure you are using the array notation for dependencies otherwise you'll have issues when mangling the code with UglifyJS or similar too.